# Regex to match not empty html link?

Tags: regex, html-parsing

What i need is very simple. If link or word is empty or whitespace, not match.

```
<a href="link">anything</a> - match
<a href="">anything</a>     - not match
<a href="link"></a>         - not match
<a href=" ">anything</a>    - not match
<a href="link"> </a>        - not match
<a href=" "> </a>           - not match
<a href=""> </a>            - not match
<a href=" "></a>            - not match
<a href=""></a>             - not match
```

What i tried first;

```
<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>
```

and i know `^a` means NOT a. But only `^` is not valid. So what syntax means NOT EMPTY?

Note: I am aware of there can be other attributes in an `a` tag.

Comment: Why don't you use a proper HTML parser instead of regexes?

Comment: You can check if the link or word is empty or whitespace by checking for the _presence_ of a non-whitespace character. Anyway, it is recommended that you consult the DOM to determine html node content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="[^"\s]+"[^>]*>[^<\s]+</a>
```

Comment: This won't allow _any_ whitespaces between the `<a>...</a>` tags.

Comment: @speakr true, but none of the test cases in the question have any whitespace :) btw, I could fix it, but I cbb

Answer (score 1):

> What i need is very simple.

Yes it is, and what you really need is XPath:

```
//a[normalize-space(@href) != ""]
```

Comment: This will match `<a href="link"> </a>` which actually shouldn't be matched. `//a[normalize-space(@href) != "" and normalize-space(text()) != ""]` should work. +1 for XPath.

Comment: @speakr: oh right. Seems what I need, is to read more carefully

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to solve this with regex you can use this:

```
/<a href="[^\s"]+">[^<]*[^<\s][^<]*<\/a>/
```

This matches everything in the `href="..."` attribute which is at least one char long and consists of no whitespaces.

Also it matches everything between the `<a>...</a>` tags which consists of at least one non-whitespace char.

If you want to allow urls containing whitespaces this regexp works:

```
/<a href="[^"]*[^\s"]+[^"]*">[^<]*[^<\s][^<]*<\/a>/
```

However, consider using a parser and a query language like XPath instead (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14480223/1337398)).

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
 /<a href="\s*\S[^"]*">\s*\S[^<]*<\/a>/
```

`\s*\S[^<]*<` means match whitespace none or more times until followed by one non-whitespace character followed by any character that is not `<` none or more times until followed by `<`.

Of course, this may fail if there are `<` between the tags.